# Making list reset subroutine not delete totals row or the formulas it contains

Tags: excel, vba

So I got the pretty snazzy piece of code below off of this forum and modified it slightly. It is perfect in that it deletes all rows of table but one, and leaves that one row with no values but all the formulas it previously contained. However, it also deletes the totals row which I need to stay in place with all of it's formulas.

Nothing that I have tried has done anything except make this code not do the other half of its job right which is to clear the table.

```
Sub ListReset(lst As ListObject)        ''clears a listobject while leaving one empty row and formulas
On Error Resume Next
With lst
  If .ShowAutoFilter Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
  If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Table is already clear
    .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Rows.Clear
  If .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then ' Check to see if SpecialCells is going to evaluate just one cell.
    .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
  ElseIf Not .Range.HasFormula Then   ' Only one cell in range and it does not contain a formula.
    .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
  End If

  .Resize .Range.Rows("1:2")
  .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Select        ' Reset used range on the sheet
        Dim X
        X = .Range.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing to `.DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to incorporate a check that the Total row is showing:

```
Sub ListReset(lst As ListObject)        ''clears a listobject while leaving one empty row and formulas

On Error Resume Next

With lst
    If .ShowAutoFilter Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    If .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Table is already clear
    If .ShowTotals Then
        .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Clear
    Else
        .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Rows.Clear
    End If
    If .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then ' Check to see if SpecialCells is going to evaluate just one cell.
        .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    ElseIf Not .Range.HasFormula Then   ' Only one cell in range and it does not contain a formula.
        .DataBodyRange.Rows(1).ClearContents
    End If
    .Resize .Range.Rows("1:2")
    .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Select        ' Reset used range on the sheet
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: worked flawlessly thank you so much! What is the best way to check if a table has an empty row at the bottom? Since I have to leave the tables with one row, then when I repopulate it, there is still a blank row in the table as my function that I repopulate it with adds a new row every time you add an item to the table. However if my function checked first to see if there was an empty row and if so used that, then if not made a new one for the values that would be way better but I have not been able to figure out what the best path is to do that

Comment: I think a table must always have at least one row. You can reference the first cell using `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value = 4`.